# Flutter: LateInitializationError: Field '_name' has not been initialized

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I recently use to using firebase core  made some changes to my code that I don't quite understand. I'm new to programming flutter. Any way, I've tried reading this similar thread here about it but I still don't quite understand it. Can someone please provide an example code of what's needed to solve for the error below?

Firebase.dart

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mybankapp/routscreens/routwidget.dart';

class FirebaseAuthMethods {

  final _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;



  //Email Registration
  Future<void> signUpWithEmail({
    required String name,
    required String email,
    required String password,
    
  }) async {
    
      await _firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email,
        password: password,
      );
      await sendEmailVerification();
      await _firestore
        .collection('users')
        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
        .set({
      'Name': name,
      'email': email,
    });
     
  }

  //Email Login
  Future<void> loginWithEmail({
    required String email,
    required String password,
  }) async {
    try{
      await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email,
        password: password,
      );
      if (!_firebaseAuth.currentUser!.emailVerified){
        await sendEmailVerification();
        //show mail not verified and mail verification is sent again.
      }else {
        NavigationBarBottom();
        //Show Home Page
      }
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e){
      e.message!;
      //show snackbar for error mwssage
    } 
  }


  //Email Verification
  Future<void> sendEmailVerification() async{
    try{
      _firebaseAuth.currentUser!.sendEmailVerification();
      //Snackbar for Verification Mail
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch(e){
      //Snackbar for error email msg
    }
  }
}
```

SignUpPage.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:mybankapp/authscreens/loginscreen.dart';
import 'package:mybankapp/colors/colors.dart';
import 'package:mybankapp/routscreens/routwidget.dart';
import 'package:mybankapp/textfontfamily/textfontfamily.dart';
import 'package:mybankapp/welcomescreen/welcomescreen.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:mybankapp/firebase_services/firebase_auth';

class SignUpScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SignUpScreenState createState() => _SignUpScreenState();
}

class _SignUpScreenState extends State<SignUpScreen> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final FirebaseAuthMethods firebaseAuthMethods = FirebaseAuthMethods();
  late String _name;
  late String _emailAddress = '';
  late String _password;
  late String _confirmPassword;

  final bool _isLoading = false;


  void signUpUser() async {
    try {
      firebaseAuthMethods.signUpWithEmail(
        name: _name,
        email: _emailAddress,
        password: _password,
      );
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      print(e.message!);
      //Snackbar for error mail
    }
    //NavigationBarBottom();
  }

  Text text(String text) {
    return Text(
      text,
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 10,
        fontFamily: TextFontFamily.helveticaNeueCyrRoman,
        color: ColorResources.white,
      ),
    );
  }

  TextFormField textFormField(String hint, String? Function(String?) validator,
      void Function(String?) onSaved,
      {bool obscureText = false}) {
    return TextFormField(
      style: TextStyle(
        fontFamily: TextFontFamily.helveticaNeueCyrRoman,
        fontSize: 13,
        color: ColorResources.grey2,
      ),
      obscureText: obscureText,
      cursorColor: ColorResources.blue1,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        filled: true,
        fillColor: ColorResources.grey1.withOpacity(0.05),
        hintText: hint,
        isDense: true,
        hintStyle: TextStyle(
          fontFamily: TextFontFamily.helveticaNeueCyrRoman,
          fontSize: 13,
          color: ColorResources.grey2,
        ),
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            width: 1,
            color: ColorResources.blue1.withOpacity(0.6),
          ),
        ),
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            width: 1,
            color: ColorResources.blue1.withOpacity(0.6),
          ),
        ),
        errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            width: 1,
            color: ColorResources.blue1.withOpacity(0.6),
          ),
        ),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            width: 1,
            color: ColorResources.blue1.withOpacity(0.6),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      validator: validator,
      onSaved: onSaved,
    );
  }

 
  // emailAddress validation
  // ignore: valid_regexps
  final _emailAddressRegExp =
      RegExp(r'^.+@[a-zA-Z]+\.{1}[a-zA-Z]+(\.{0,1}[a-zA-Z]+)$');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: ColorResources.backGroundColor,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50, left: 15, right: 15),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  Get.off(WelcomeScreen());
                },
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.close,
                  color: ColorResources.white,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 70),
              Text(
                "Create Account",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: TextFontFamily.helveticNeueCyrBold,
                    fontSize: 35,
                    color: ColorResources.red),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 7),
              Text(
                "Open a Noble Bank account with a few details.",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: TextFontFamily.helveticaNeueCyrRoman,
                    fontSize: 15,
                    color: ColorResources.white1),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 40),
              Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    text("Full name"),
                    SizedBox(height: 10),
                    textFormField("", (value) {
                      if (value!.isEmpty) {
                        return "Please enter your name";
                      }
                      return null;
                    }, (value) {
                      _name = value!;
                    }),
                    SizedBox(height: 20),
                    text("Email Address"),
                    SizedBox(height: 10),
                    textFormField("", (value) {
                      if (!_emailAddressRegExp.hasMatch(value!)) {
                        return "Please enter your email address";
                      }
                      return null;
                    }, (value) {
                      _emailAddress = value!;
                    }),
                    SizedBox(height: 20),
                    text("Password"),
                    SizedBox(height: 10),
                    textFormField("", (value) {
                      if (value!.isEmpty) {
                        return "Please enter your password";
                      } else if (value.length < 8) {
                        return "Password must be at least 8 characters long";
                      }
                      return null;
                    }, (value) {
                      _password = value!;
                    }, obscureText: true),
                    SizedBox(height: 20),
                    text("Repeat password"),
                    SizedBox(height: 10),
                    textFormField("", (value) {
                      if (value!.isEmpty) {
                        return "Please enter your password";
                      } else if (value != _password) {
                        return "Password doesn't match";
                      }
                      return null;
                    }, (value) {
                      _confirmPassword = value!;
                    }, obscureText: true),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: Get.height >= 876 ? 150 : 50),
              _isLoading
                  ? CircularProgressIndicator()
                  : SizedBox(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: InkWell(
                        onTap: signUpUser,
                        child: Container(
                          height: 50,
                          width: Get.width,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: ColorResources.red,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          ),
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text(
                              "CREATE YOUR FREE ACCOUNT",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontFamily:
                                      TextFontFamily.helveticaNeueCyrRoman,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                  fontSize: 13.5,
                                  color: ColorResources.white),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              Center(
                child: RichText(
                  text: TextSpan(
                    text: "Do you already have a Noble Bank account?",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 13.5,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                      fontFamily: TextFontFamily.helveticaNeueCyrRoman,
                      color: ColorResources.white2,
                    ),
                    children: <TextSpan>[
                      TextSpan(
                        recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                          ..onTap = () => Get.to(LogInScreen()),
                        text: "  Sign in here",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 14,
                          fontFamily: TextFontFamily.helveticaNeueCyrRoman,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                          color: ColorResources.red,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: See how to use late variables: https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#late-variables.

Comment: I did not quite understand that well, please can you explain? or check my code for more clarity?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot guarantee that `_name` (and the other fields) are set to a valid value before you call `signUpUser()`, you should not make the `late`.

Instead, make them nullable as in

```
String? _name;
```

And check for non-null values bevor using the data to create the user account.

Comment: Thank you, I alerady change it text controller

Comment: @Radiant remember, if you find an answer useful, you can up-vote of mark it as the accepted answer. This will allow others to identify the most useful information on this site. Saying "thank you" in the comments is not necessary.

Comment: none of the answers worked, I had to change restructure the whole code and change it to textcontroller.